# Error when bringing rails 2.3.5 app to 3.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9

So I've been using a PDF guide to help bring my application from 2.3.2 to 3.0.7. I'm still relatively new at this ... but I've managed to use the rails_upgrade plugin to help convert my route files and other config files. But when it comes to running the server I get this error:

```
/home/***********/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:284:in `activate': Unable to activate railties-3.0.7, because activesupport-2.3.2 conflicts with activesupport (= 3.0.7), actionpack-2.3.2 conflicts with actionpack (= 3.0.7) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/***********/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:212:in `rescue in try_activate'
    from /home/***********/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `try_activate'
    from /home/***********/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:57:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/***********/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

now I have tried clean installing rvm, and installing a few libraries mentioned in other posts to no avail. my gem list is as follows:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.7)
actionpack (3.0.7, 2.3.2)
activemodel (3.0.7)
activerecord (3.0.7)
activeresource (3.0.7)
activesupport (3.0.7, 2.3.2)
arel (2.0.9)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.13)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.1.3, 1.0.10)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
mongrel (1.2.0.pre2)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.2)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.7)
railties (3.0.7)
rake (0.8.7)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
```

Does anyone have a clue what the solution to this would be? It occurs when I run rails s (or rails server).

I apologize if the answer to this question is blatantly obvious, but I've searched and searched and can't seem to find something specific enough for my situation.

thank you for your help.

n.b.
the ***'s are just where I search and replaced my user name.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling the 2.3.2 versions of activesupport and actionpack.  I think the syntax is...

```
gem uninstall activesupport actionpack -v 2.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to upgrade rails because the error is stating a version conflict between the different gems rails uses.

It really depends on how you are managing gems `gem update rails`.